# How to use update from select in postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

```
update users
set users.przetwarzanie = historia_panel.zmiana_z
from historia_panel 
where 
        users.user_number like historia_panel.user_number and
        historia_panel.zmienna_zmieniana like '%przetwarzanie%' and
        historia_panel.przyczyna like '%użytkownika%';
```

And the error is:

```
The error that is in console:
ERROR:  column "users" of relation "users" does not exist
LINE 2: set users.przetwarzanie = historia_panel.zmiana_z
```

In this query i want to update `users` table with values from `historia_panel` table with specified conditions. I tried many different ways but none of examples that i found on the internet works.

Actualy i have no idea what I'am doing wrong...

Answer (score 2):

The error would suggest that you aren't allowed to qualify the column names in the `set` clause; and indeed you shouldn't need to since you already said `update users`

Whether that's the only problem I can't say at a quick glance, but that is what the error message is telling you; so try changing `set users.przetwarzanie = historia_panel.zmiana_z` to just `set przetwarzanie = historia_panel.zmiana_z` and see what you get

Comment: `ERROR:  column "przetwarzanie" is of type integer but expression is of type character varying
LINE 2: set przetwarzanie = historia_panel.zmiana_z` that's what i got. I think the problem is with the `update users`. It should be in one `FROM` statement or something like this. And still i have no idea how to solve this error but thanks for answer ;)

Comment: Not sure why you think the problem is with the `update users`; that's not at all what the error message says.  It says you're assigning character data to an integer.  First of all that means processing got far enough that the problem you keep wanting to look for (overall problem with query structure) doesn't exist.  Secondly, you need to know your data.  The error arises because pg doesn't want to be put in the position of guessing what to do if it finds itself being told to assign a value like 'HELLO' to a column that only accepts numbers, as assigning a varchar to an integer could do

Comment: Yeah you are right. ;) I changed it reinterpret type of `historia_panel.zmienna_z` to `int` by adding `::int:

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with incompatible typles between two columns from different tables. I added line `set przetwarzanie = historia_panel.zmiana_z::int` and now it works.

Comment: The real question is: why are you storing numbers in a `varchar` column?

Comment: I'am using varchar because historia_panel is a history log of changes made by users on their accounts. Users can change for example username and this change is stored in `historia_panel`. I'm not the one who created this table but I'm the one who need to restore some changes from `historia_panel` and apply these changes to `users` table. ;)